# How to choose a RNN cell from a list of RNN cells during runtime in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, control-flow

My network requires a number of independent `MultiRNNCells`, stored as a python list `multirnn_cells` right now. And during runtime, based on the value of a scalar placeholder `i`, I need to do step through the respective RNN cell `multirnn_cells[i]`. How can I do this?

I noticed in the TensorFlow control flow documentation about `tf.case`. This is not suitable since `tf.case` expects the tuple functions to return tensors and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but even if it is, this would be a really dirty hack. For a number of reasons:

- Tensorflow is designed to run in very specific environments, such as GPU memory. As a result the *runtime* can operate only with numeric values and some predefined primitive types (such as strings). It can not work with arbitrary python objects, which each of `MultiRNNCell` instances are, that's why API is forcing you to pass tensors as input and returns tensors as output.
- Any RNN cell in tensorflow, `MultiRNNCell` in particular, is a *factory*. It merely encapsulates the way the cells are created in a graph, and normally is useless after the graph is built. If you want to use it at runtime, i.e. create new cells at runtime and expand the graph, it's a quick path to OOM errors. If you mean to use the RNN layers that are already instantiated, these are normal tensors, not `MultiRNNCell` cells.

Bottom line: I strongly advise you *against* the described approach.

Comment: I understand. But do you have any suggestion regarding how I should approach this problem? I need to be able to choose between the RNN parameters during runtime based on the input placeholder. I don't see how I can do this apart from writing custom RNN cells by myself.

Comment: Custom RNN cells is a much better solution